# can't use scroll function correctly after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, onclick

I made a function that increment class on a `li` list everytime i scroll on the page, so now i want to make the function on click but there is a conflict, for example if i click and i want to scroll again the increment function stop, how can i fix it ?

```js
var scrollable = $('ul li').length - 1,
  count = 0,
  allowTransition = true;
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {

  if (allowTransition) {
    allowTransition=false;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      if (scrollable >= count && count > 0) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
        count--
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (scrollable > count) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        count++
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      allowTransition=true;
    }, 1000);
  }
});

$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  $('ul li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  }

ul li {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none
}
ul li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working script http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/oLWZjY

you needed to reset allowTransition flag andd update the current count

```js
var scrollable = $('ul li').length - 1,
  count = 0,
  allowTransition = true;
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  //alert(count);
  if (allowTransition) {
    allowTransition=false;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      if (scrollable >= count && count > 0) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
      count--;
      } else {
        allowTransition=true;
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (scrollable > count) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      count++;
      } else {
        allowTransition=true;
        return false;
      }

    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      allowTransition=true;
    }, 1000);
  }
});

$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  $('ul li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  count = $(this).attr('count');
  allowTransition=true;
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
  }

ul li {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none
}
ul li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
      <li class="active" count='0'></li>
      <li count='1'></li>
      <li count='2'></li>
      <li count='3'></li>
    </ul>
```